# why 2.23 + 0.17 = 2.4899999999999998 in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point

Why does

`2.23 + 0.17 = 2.4899999999999998`

but

`1.23 + 0.17 = 1.49`

Screenshot from a debug console:

[image]

Comment: [What every programmer should know about floting point arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: The same reason 1/3 * 3 = .9999999 in fixed-digit decimal. The nature of fixed precision representations is that they, at least sometimes, return approximate results.

Comment: There are many identical questions. I don't have any of them bookmarked but the word to search would probably be "IEEE754".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the magic of floating point numbers :)

You can read [some interesting things about it](http://floating-point-gui.de). Also, there are solutions for that problems.

Comment: +1 Nice comprehension of the link I gave above. Didn't know that one.